# How do Windows application crashes work internally?

Tags: windows, crash, windows-error-reporting, unresponsive, computer-behavior

Specifically: What is the difference between these Windows application crash behaviors:

- Closing instantly ("crash to desktop")
- White overlay with "busy" cursor and messagebox
- Application freezed forever without error message (mostly games in exclusive fullscreen mode)

And how can the Windows crash messages (like "X has stopped working" or "X is not responding"), the available options or the design be changed by the software?

[image: Message box example 1]

[image: Message box example 2]

Comment: Which _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Operating System Version are you talking about?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Windows 10

Comment: Indeed, interesting question. We are more interested in the first part: '_Closing instantly ("crash to desktop")_'. Are you referring to the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Universal Windows Platform_ Static Software Applications, also known as _Metro_ Tiles?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai No, just in general.